# Excel 2010 - Lookup multiple values on other sheets in response to clicking a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take specific information from one sheet, and have it show in another according to what a specific cell is showing.

What i have so far:
When i click any cell in my work sheet, it shows the information for that given row in D3-I3.

What i want:
Take the information from F3 and I3 and reference the prices in another sheet (Price Sheeet), and show them in E4-E7. This way i can update only my price page, and it will show that price on my inventory sheets. 
I want them to change as i click around, same as the code does already.

Code im using thus far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 0 And Target.Column > 0 Then
        Range("D2").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value
        Range("E2").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value
        Range("F2").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value
        Range("G2").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value
        Range("H2").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value
        Range("I2").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I rearranged where I want my prices to show, and how I would like it to look in the image linked below. (Mock Inventory sheet)
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAKSH.png

and here's a mock of my price sheet.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEq95.png

Please read comment replys.

Comment: Please, Ryan, be more specific in your example and correct in your wording.

Comment: I dont understand how to be more specific. In the picture, it shows in the top 8 frozen panes were i want the info from another sheet placed. When F:3 and I:3 show a certain size and interface, i want it to pull the price info for that specific size and interface in E4, E5, E6, E7.

Comment: So this particular example (screenshot) would pull info from G2, G3, G4, G5 from Price Sheeet. (added another picture to the OP)

Comment: I'm sorry for so many edits and comments, but this is just been a problem that ive been trying to solve for many many weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to use regular functions in this case

the strategy I would use in this case is to first search for the column that your GB resides in.

```
=MATCH(F3,Prices!1:1,0)
```

for 20gb, this would return "7" meaning it is in the 7th column from the left (column G)

i would then search for the interface row. i see you have a choice between 2.5 and 3.5 options so a simple if statement would need to be made (but that isn't included in your example sheet so im assuming 3.5)

```
=MATCH(I3,Prices!A:A,0)
```

in your example, it would return 3 (row 3). since we now have the x and y it is pretty easy to reference that cell and there are a number of different ways to do it.

one way is to do an offset. in your 'price' cell you would want something like this:

```
=OFFSET(Prices!A1,MATCH(I3,Prices!A:A,0)-1,MATCH(F3,Prices!1:1,0)-1)
```

what this does is look at cell a1 in the prices worksheet (your reference), and tells it to move 3-1 rows down (rows operator), and tells it to move 7-1 rows to the right (columns operator)

you could then adjust your row offset to fit your other fields like cost accept, and decline. cost would be -1, accept = +1, decline = +2

cost =

```
=OFFSET(Prices!A1,MATCH(I3,Prices!A:A,0)-2,MATCH(F3,Prices!1:1,0)-1)
```

you could set this logic up for 3.5 and 2.5 situations and do a logical test that if product = 2.5, then use 2.5 model. else use 3.5 model. but you may need to tweak your existing book to do that

additionally, you may need to tweak this to actually fit your book since i had to recreate the data and may have some of my columns misaligned

Comment: Ok, It's not searching for Row. I used the 2nd code you gave me, and put my sheet name in it as i did for the first, and it didnt work. (The first one did)

Comment: My sheet is named PriceSheeet so i would replace your "Prices!" with "PriceSheeet!" correct? It keeps showing me an #N/A

Comment: I figured out the Row part.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i'm understanding your question correctly...But you mentioned you want to transfer data from one sheet to another based on a value in a specific cell. You could use a simple IF statement formula to locate value in cell and transfer another cells data over. Just make sure you use Relative Cell References as needed($).

=IF(Sheet1!$C$4=859,Sheet1!$A2,"")